# Two Pass encoding FFMpeg C/C++

Tags: c++, c, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

From different days I'm trying to implement the two pass encoding `h264` in `ffmpeg` without success. I understand that in the first pass I need to create a text file with the statistics that are in `stats_out`. This step is realized internally from `ffmpeg`, so I need set the first pass and have the data in `stats_out` and after I need go to pass 2.

For now I'm trying to activate the pass 1 in different way adding the flag in the codecContext:

```
CodecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_PASS1;
```

and/or set the option before the creation of context:

```
av_opt_set(CodecCtx, "pass", "1", 0);
```

but in any way i have the same result, stats_out is always (null).

Also in the investigation i discovery this `FF_API_STATS_BIT` that seems to be deprecated:

## if FF_API_STAT_BITS

```
/* statistics, used for 2-pass encoding */
attribute_deprecated
int mv_bits;
attribute_deprecated
int header_bits;
attribute_deprecated
int i_tex_bits;
attribute_deprecated
int p_tex_bits;
attribute_deprecated
int i_count;
attribute_deprecated
int p_count;
attribute_deprecated
int skip_count;
attribute_deprecated
int misc_bits;

/** @deprecated this field is unused */
attribute_deprecated
int frame_bits;
```

## endif

So there is i little bit of ambiguity on how to realize this process and the relative posts  are too old and not very usefull.

There is anyone that had experience on it?

Comment: I cannot read the screen shot. Please post text as text.

Comment: Have you set the output log path ? `av_opt_set(CodecCtx->priv_data, "stats", "mylogfile", 0);`

Comment: I tried but it not make any differece, more, for me : av_opt_set(CodecCtx->priv_data, "stats", "mylogfile", 0); and av_opt_set(CodecCtx, "pass", "1", 0); return value < 0